# I2C with DS1307 hang after end of transmission

Tags: arduino, i2c, rtc

I've got a home brewed RTC with [DS1307](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1307.pdf). I've put two pullup resistors on SDA and SCL lines, connected them to the Arduino 5 and 6 pin respectively. I've also provided a backup battery since I read sometimes the RTC can hang if there is not a proper backup voltage. 
The arduino program hangs on the instruction:

```
int err = Wire.endTransmission();
```

I guess there is no reply from the device so SW wait indefinitely.
Strangely if I remove the I2C conenctions, endOfTrasmission returns a NACK error code ( I say strangely because I better expect an hang without any device connected ).
I have no idea on what to test, I suspect the DS1307 being damaged by some adventurous test in swapping `A5-A6` data but I have no idea of how to make this diagnosis.

Comment: What sense would it make to hang the write if the slave doesn't ACK? It's not like it might come back later; it's missed its chance. More likely, the DS1307 is holding down the SCL line. The master would interpret this as a "clock-stretch" and could wait indefinitely for it to be released. As you say, you may have damaged the chip or you have a short on the package.

Comment: Please share a more complete block of code, simplified to the bare-minimum functionality desired. It is conceivable that the `Wire.endTransmission()` line is not where it is hanging, but some subsequent line.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I did a lot of tracing and I can confirm it hang on endTrasmission() ie when it try to actually send the data.

Comment: @FelicePollano You aren't making it easy for people to try figuring out the issue, by not sharing a minimal code block that others can at least try to use on their own systems.

Comment: @DoxyLover you are correct: there was a short between SCW and SCL kkeping, as you said, low the clock signal. Now it works like a charm. If you want send a reply I will vote and accept, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reposting my comment as an answer]

What sense would it make to hang the write if the slave doesn't ACK? It's not like it might come back later; it's missed its chance. More likely, the DS1307 is holding down the SCL line. The master would interpret this as a "clock-stretch" and could wait indefinitely for it to be released. As you say, you may have damaged the chip or you have a short on the package.